# M24 and 15/16” aerators aren’t fitting

Tags: faucet, bathtub

M24 and 15/16” aerators aren’t fitting

When we purchased our home, the bathtub’s faucet in the master bath no longer had the male aerator attached. I measured the diameter of the opening and found it was about an inch. So I assumed the 15/16” adapter would work. It *seemed* like it would fit, but it wouldn’t stay. So I tried an M24 aerator and that definitely fit and stayed, but falls out at the slightest touch or whenever you start the water. My tub has no markings of the actual manufacturer, so I’m grasping at straws at this point.

Could it be a M28? If so, where would I find that type of part... I’m struggling to find one online. Or could it be that the M24 should work but maybe the threading isn’t matching up with the female component? If so, how would I solve for that?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Tub faucet]

[image: Tub with M24 aerator]

[image: M24 aerator]

Answer (score 1):

The threading on the faucet looks ok. Amazon has 28mm aerators. I wish I could tell you an easy way to get what you need but at this point it's trial and error. I once bought three different sizes to try and match one to a faucet. Luckily, I got one right and was able to return the rest. Good luck.*

Comment: Just got 28mm from Amazon. Too big, unfortunately.